# Running Windows Server 2022 install from within Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-server

A PC I just purchased came loaded with Windows 10, though I wanted to install Windows Server 2022 on it (datacenter, desktop experience).

To do so, I downloaded the ISO, mounted it in Windows 10, and then ran setup.exe from within that mount.

When setup finished, I was expecting some kind of dual boot scenario, and my plan was to use a partition manager to then remove Windows 10.

However, it seems all I ended up with is Windows Server 2022, and Windows 10 is no longer in sight. Without knowing it, did I perform some kind of upgrade?

And is what I ended up with different from what I'd have gotten installing Windows Server 2022 cold, i.e. from installation media onto a machine without anything on the hard drive?

Thank you!

Comment: “Without knowing it, did I perform some kind of upgrade?” - You installed Windows Server over Windows 10. There is no difference in this case between installing from WinRE and installing from within Windows

Comment: @Ramhound ok, thank you. From what you know, would there be aspects of Windows 10 that 'carry over'? At some point I may need to document my setup for a security team, and I'm wondering if I can safely assume that this is equivalent to a cold Windows Server 2022 install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did what is called "in-place upgrade", which means installing one
Windows version from within another, which is why this is called
"upgrade" and not installation.

This is different from installing on an empty disk, because you keep
many objects from the previous version : User accounts,
installed applications, user data, many Windows settings and
almost all drivers.
This includes any applications installed by the manufacturer.

Installing by booting from USB would have had the same effect,
as the installation would have detected the installed Windows version
and would have attempted to upgrade it.

For doing a truly cold install from USB, you should format the disk
before installing. This will install standard Windows with its
generic drivers, which might require searching for the
missing drivers on the manufacturer's website.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thank you!

Comment: Technically, they performed a clean install of Windows Server on top of Windows 10. There is no upgrade path from Windows 10 to Windows Server.

Comment: @Ramhound: That puzzled me too, but it seemed to have worked for the poster. Perhaps because, although officially there is no official upgrade path, the two Windows versions are almost identical. For future readers: Not sure that this will keep on working.

Comment: @harrymc - As I said they performed a clean install, while within Windows 10, it’s how you downgrade to an earlier build.

Comment: I did actually notice that a local user I'd created in Windows 10 was no longer present